# Geofencing doesn't rise event in foreground

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

it's first time I am developing app with geofencing. I have problem, that geofence does not rise an event, when device is going into desired arena. I checked msdn and everything should be fine. Here's my code:

```
var _geolocator = new Geolocator();
BasicGeoposition pitchPosition;
pitchPosition.Latitude = 45.045213;
pitchPosition.Longitude = 19.040611;
pitchPosition.Altitude = 0.0;
double radius = 300;
Geocircle shape = new Geocircle(pitchPosition,radius);
MonitoredGeofenceStates monitoredGeofenceStates = MonitoredGeofenceStates.Entered;
TimeSpan timeToTrigger = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
TimeSpan activeTimeSpan = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
DateTimeOffset startTime = DateTime.Now;
var _geofence = new Geofence(GeofenceId,shape,monitoredGeofenceStates,false,timeToTrigger,startTime,activeTimeSpan);   GeofenceMonitor.Current.GeofenceStateChanged += OnGeofenceStateChanged;
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost: You are not adding the geofence to the monitor:

```
GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Add(_geofence);
```

Also you should consider a bigger dwell time so that the event has more time to be processed. Sometimes the geofence monitor on your phone needs some time to learn (especially in the emulator).

For instance: If your geofence is rather small and you're crossing it with high speed, chances are that your event won't fire at all. In the beginning, try setting big fences and approach them slowly. The geofence monitor will adjust to your movement profile over time.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now :) However, MSDN documentation missed that line. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn322032.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn322030.aspx